# Remove category level from top navigation menu (topMenu)

Tags: navigation, menu

I have a category structure which goes Socks>>Casual>>No-Show, Crew  and would like the URL to be socks/casual/no-show.html, for example.

However, I would like the generated top navigation menu ("topMenu") to *skip* the 2nd level, i.e. "Casual", so that the dropdown menu shows Sock>>No-Show, Crew.

What's the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can create URL rewrites for all your categories where the 2nd token has to be dropped. Then you can observe `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after` event and modify the main menu links.